# How to update a file/image in ROR using AWS S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm developing an image editing app in Ruby on Rails, and I want to update my image on AWS S3 cloud storage.
Currently I have a system where the user signs in, then using Carrierwave uploader uploads the image on S3 using fog in production,
then I have an AJAX call to the controller which triggers the editing using mini_magick gem, then finally reloading the image.

The problem is that I don't know how to reupload it on S3 (updating the image), locally it works fine, but the problem is in production on Heroku with S3.

One of the answers was this, but for me it doesn't work: (AWS::S3::S3Object.store 's3/path/to/untitled.txt', params[:textarea_contents_params_name], your_bucket_name).

This is my code:

```
def flip # controller
    imagesource = params["imagesource"].to_s # URL

    image = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{imagesource}")
    image.combine_options do |i|
      i.flip
    end
    # image.write "#{imagesource}" # development

    # production
    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
        :access_key_id     => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        :secret_access_key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    )
    AWS::S3::S3Object.store '#{imagesource}', image, 'mybucket'
    AWS::S3::S3Object.store('#{imagesource}', open(image), 'mybucket') #2nd attempt

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => {:result => image}}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the file to disk (as you do in the development) before attempting to upload the file to disk. Your code should explicitly write the data to a temporary location (eg use a Tempfile) rather than let that location be controlled by input from the user

If as the comment suggests the user input is a URL, [recent security updates](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/891) may prevent you from directly passing a URL to minimagick. If so download the image first (to a temporary file) and then pass that to minimagick.

It looks like you are using [aws-s3](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/object.rb) for your s3 uploads (super old and maintained etc). If so, it's not completely clear what the values of the parameters are, but when you upload the image to s3 you probably  only specify the path portion of the URL. The second argument to `store` can either be an IO object (such as an instance of File) or a string containing the actual data.

Comment: First I'll test the mini_magick open function using URL, but I did read that it still works, you can disallow this in policy.xml file. As far as aws-s3 gem being old can I use something else that is maybe easier or better, because I don't like the idea of writing the image on disc and then deleting the previous version and uploading the new version. But still thanks :)